# Visual Basic API returns an exception error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a new leg in a WebAPI that I have written in visual basic.  The code I am trying to execute is this:

```
Public Class getDatabaseDataController
Inherits ApiController
    Private product_information As getDatabaseData() = New getDatabaseData() _
    {New getDatabaseData() With {
    .return_response = "return response"
}}

    Public Function GetCars(<FromUri> ByVal dbRequest As String) As IEnumerable(Of getDatabaseData)

        Dim return_string As String = ""
        Dim passedData As String = dbRequest

        return_string = passedData

        Dim mqResponse As getDatabaseData() = New getDatabaseData() _
            {New getDatabaseData() With {
            .return_response = Str(return_string)
            }}
        'Return product_information
        Return mqResponse

    End Function
End Class
```

I have a public class called getDatabaseData defined as follows:

```
Public Class getDatabaseData
    Private _Return_Response As String
    Public Property return_response() As String
        Get
            Return _Return_Response
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Return_Response = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I call the API with this call:

> http://localhost:12976/api/getDatabaseData?dbRequest=A

All I am trying to do at this point is have the API return the value A.  When I debug the API and send in the request, this is what is returned:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
        <ExceptionMessage>
Argument 'Number' cannot be converted to a numeric value.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException</ExceptionType>
```

I dont see anything in the code that would indicate a 'Numeric'.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You are missing a debugger.  Google "vb.net debugger stop on first chance exception" to get ahead.

Comment: I clicked on Debug->Windows->Exception Settings and checked off common language runtime exceptions->System.InvalidCastException since that is what I saw in the ExceptionType tag.  Then I re-started the debugging session and entered the url.  I still get the same exact error message.

Comment: Be sure to debug the server and not the client app.

Comment: How do I debug the server?  And why wouldn't the debug session stop at any breakpoint that I set in my code?  very strange.

Comment: Google "how to debug an asp.net webapi" to get ahead.

Comment: I dont know if this means anything but when I send in http://localhost:12976/api/getDatabaseData?dbRequest=1 to the API, the response back is <return_response> 1</return_response>.  If I send in http://localhost:12976/api/getDatabaseData?dbRequest=1111, the response back is <return_response> 1111</return_response>. So, why does this error when I send in characters in the url as opposed to numbers?